# Allure report: nothing shown in Chrome

Tags: java, maven, webdriver, report, allure

I'm trying to use [Allure-framework](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core) to generate a report for my [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) tests. I use `JUnit` framework and [allure-maven-plugin](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/Allure-Maven-Plugin) with version 1.3.9 of Allure. I run tests with `mvn test` then generate the report using `mvn site`. I see generated report in `target/site/allure-maven-plugin/` directory. When I open **index.html** page with Firefox it works normally. However when doing the same thing in Chrome or Safari **I see nothing**.

What's wrong? Am I missing something? My `pom.xml` file is located [here](https://gist.github.com/just-boris/961cedf9d506ee29173c).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This problem is related to default Webkit security settings which forbid doing Ajax requests on the local filesystem. You have at least two possible solutions:

1. Serve **index.html** with some web-server like Nginx or Apache. This will emulate remote website and thus trick your browser. With Allure CLI 2.0+ this can be done using the following command:

> $ allure report open

2. Use **--allow-file-access-from-files** Chrome flag. See details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487803/why-does-this-filesystem-api-requestquota-call-fail).

Comment: If you're using Java and Maven you can also use Jetty and respective [plugin for Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-maven-plugin).

Comment: Btw, if you're not 100% Chrome fan you can simply use Firefox which doesn't have this issue.

Comment: slight change in the command as of Sep 2019.
allure open <Allure-Reports-Directory>
command: allure open Allure-Reports

Answer (score 8):

To use allure report in chrome, you have two options:

- Use `mvn allure:serve` target. It will generate the report and open a tab in Chrome (if default browser)
- Generate the report using `mvn allure:report` target and serve the site your self, using any http server. if you have node you can use `http-server` for example `npm install http-server -g` and then `http-server target/site/allure-maven-plugin`)

**DO NOT use `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag, is it DANDEGEROUS**

Comment: `mvn io.qameta.allure:allure-maven:serve` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

To open your report in Chrome browser use the below command in cmd prompt

`allure open path_to_allure_report_folder`

or use the below command if above command does not work

`allure serve path_to_allure_report_folder`

This will open your report.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by following below steps .

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Ry0.png) Close all instances of chrome.
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL7VB.png) Enable local file access by executing below command.

```
C:\Users\vikas.piprade>"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

[3] Relaunch terminal and view  allure reports by *"allure generate"* followed by *"allure open"* commands.

Before :: allure report has no data and showing loading...  -
[image]

After :: allure report started showing data -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.24, Allure has introduced a single HTML file report generation mode.

To enable it, you need to specify `--single-file` option for `generate` command:

```
$ allure generate --single-file path/to/allure-results
```

The `allure-report/index.html` file will be generated, which can be opened directly in the browser without starting a web service.

Details: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/pull/2072

Answer (score -3):

In Addition to the above answer using "--ignore-certifcate-errors" with chromeOptions might be helpfull.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certifcate-errors");
chromeOptions.addArguments("test-type");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: it's not relevant to the question