# WebDriver.io no console output

Tags: javascript, selenium, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am using the following stack to run several tests:

```
NodeJs
Selenium standalone
geckodriver thought I use chrome
webdriver.io
mocha 
chai
```

So after all my first_test.js is:

```
describe ('Website url test ', () => {
  it('should have a title ', () => {
    browser.call((done) => {
      browser.url('http://webdriver.io');
      var title = browser.getTitle();
      expect(title).to.be.equal('WebdriverIO - WebDriver bindings for Node.js')
      done();
    })
  })
```

And the output in the console is:Incorrect console output

[image]

But it should be like this for the passing tests as well: Correct console output

[image]

Is something in Mocha config that I should change so that the passing tests would produce the same optical outcome?

Answer (score 4):

This behavior was caused by the reporter chosen (in my case **[dot](http://webdriver.io/guide/reporters/dot.html)**).

I changed to **[spec](http://webdriver.io/guide/reporters/spec.html)** and I have a very verbose output now.

Answer (score 4):

**[WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io)** supports a great variety of reporters:

- **[Dot](http://webdriver.io/guide/reporters/dot.html)**: which is the default reporter for WDIO, a lightweight console reporter that outputs a green, or red dot (**'.'**) for a passing, respectively failing test case;
- **[Spec](http://webdriver.io/guide/reporters/spec.html)**: which just outputs in the console a step-by-step breakdown of the test cases you previously ran. This output will reside **strictly in the console**, unless you want to pipe your entire console log-stack via the `logOutput: './<yourLogFolderPath>/'` attribute from the **wdio.conf.js** file;
- **[Json](http://webdriver.io/guide/reporters/json.html)**: which generates a `.json` report of the tests your previously ran. It's very well suited for people who already have a **test results dashboard** where they analyze their regression results (passing tests, failing tests, run-time, etc.) and just need to parse the data from somewhere. You can configure the path where you want the `.json` report to be generated via:

  `reporterOptions: {
      outputDir: './<yourLogFolderPath>'
    }`

**Note:** The Json reporter will populate the path given with `WDIO-<timestamp>.json` reports. If you want to pipe said `.json` to some other software for parsing, then you will need to go inside the library and change the naming convention so that you always get your results in the same file as opposed to a dynamically generated one.

- **[Allure](http://webdriver.io/guide/reporters/allure.html)**: Allure is one of the best reporter choices, especially if you don't have the makings of a **test results dashboard** in place as it generates one for you. You can check out **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531706/generate-html-report-for-webdriverio-cucumber-framework/44685029#44685029)** answer for a step-by-step breakdown;

**!!! BUT** as a best practice, no reporter should outweigh the importance of setting your [`logLevel`](https://webdriver.io/docs/options.html#loglevel)  (*inside the **wdio.conf.js** file*) to **debug** (`logLevel: 'debug'`) for `wdio-v5`, or **verbose** (`logLevel: 'verbose'`) for `wdio-v4`.

When **debugging** (I presume that was the reason purpose with the reporting), it's crucial that you get to the root of the problem in the fastest way possible and that is by looking at the **REST** calls made by your tests during run-time.

Hope this give a clearer overview to people starting with WebdriverIO and who need more info regarding which of these reporters is best suited for what scenario/situation.

Cheers!