# Unable to open generated allure report on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: allure

allure report is working in edge browser and chrome browser. But not working on IE 11. Getting 404 in IE browser.

[image]

Comment: it will work in firefox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allure report: nothing shown in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997449/allure-report-nothing-shown-in-chrome)

Comment: I can able to open in Chrome browser by using " --allow-file-access-from-files" but it's not working in Internet Explorer 11