# Allure Report Executes but Fails to Populate Data - Jasmine and Protractor

Tags: npm, jasmine, protractor, reporting, allure

I have set up a Protractor project that uses Allure Reporting. I have managed to get Allure Reporter outputting the HTML file to the allure-report folder, but upon opening the page in the browser it just says "Loading..." on the overview page. When I click on the other tabs, I get a 404 page not found message.

The package.json file contains a scripts section that specifies the test and post-test scripts to run:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "protractor conf.js",
    "posttest": "allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report || true"
  },
```

The problem seems to reside in the line:

```
allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report || true
```

Can anyone advise what I would need to change in package.json in order to populate my report? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

When I run `allure serve allure-results` 
I get the formatted HTML report as expected, but I need to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the report if you open `index.html` file in `FireFox` browser. Probably you have opened this in `Chrome` browser. The error you are getting because of default Webkit security settings. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24002146/2372510).

Comment: No, that's not made any difference.

Comment: Please refer to this sample repository. https://github.com/jithinkmatthew/protractor-code

Comment: Are you trying to run it through Jenkin?

Comment: No, running it locally at the minute, will be moving it on to a Jenkins job at a later stage. I'd like to get it working correctly locally first. It's a Mac I'm using too so not sure if there's any issue arising from that?

Comment: Successfully generated report with the above sample project. Also, ensure that you have installed `npm i allure-commandline`