# Allure report is not getting loaded, for cucumber 7

Tags: junit4, maven-plugin, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin, allure

## I could generate Allure report, but not able view them as it is not getting loaded.

## tech stack: Cucumber-java 7, junit4, maven

**Adding below plugins I added to my pom.xml file for allure.**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>
            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
            -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm"
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <reportVersion>${allure.version}</reportVersion>
        <resultsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</resultsDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

*And below are the versions I used for cucumber, junit4 and allure. *
**Dependencies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-cucumber7-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
</dependency>
```

*after running build tried the command 'allure serve allure-results' and also tried the command 'allure generate allure-results'.
and then open the index.html on browser getting *
[Scrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F23c7.png)
`

Comment: Please use ``` on a new line to highlight code snippets

Answer (score 0):

That is a known issue - simple solution is open report in Firefox for example.
Full answer can be found here: [Allure report: nothing shown in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997449/allure-report-nothing-shown-in-chrome)