# Allure report stuck with a loading spinner after launching index.html from generated report

Tags: python, automation, report, allure, python-behave

I've used the below code to generate the allure report, but after generation when I launch the index.html file it keeps on loading. But when I use serve command and launch it, the proper report gets generated but its not stored somewhere(with serve command) so I can share it across mail to someone

[Allure report that keeps on loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx3Io.png)

```
allure_generate_command = f"allure generate Report\\allure_result -o Report\\allure_report_{timestamp}"
subprocess.run(allure_generate_command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to default Webkit security settings, which forbid doing Ajax requests on the local filesystem.

The difference between `serve` commands is that `serve` generates the report to the temp folder and starts web service to host the report. The `generate` command only produces static report files to the file system.

For the solution, please follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/78205486/3915166

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitry Baev, That helped me to solve the issue.